# Split json-format column into multiple columns in Redshift

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

```
select feature_column from table

{"reporting": true, "newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": false, "customer_feedback": true, "reserve_with_google": true, "new_closingtime_background": true, "merchant_logo_on_customer_email": true}
{"messaging": false, "yext_sync": false, "marketplace": false, "newsletters": false, "ranking_coach": false, "sms_reminders": false, "sms_newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": true, "customer_feedback": true, "birthday_reminders": false, "merchant_dashboard": true, "merchant_shiftplan": false, "reserve_with_google": false, "sms_customer_confirmation": false, "individual_email_from_name": true, "appointment_location_customer": false}
{"messaging": false, "newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": false, "birthday_reminders": false, "merchant_shiftplan": false, "double_opt_in_required": false, "new_closingtime_background": true, "facebook_instagram_integration": true, "show_all_branch_option_on_insights": true, "show_newsletter_non_subscriber_selection": false}
```

Instead of having all these values stored in one column, I would like to convert it into a tabular form:

```
No. reporting      newsletters       merchant_payment       customer_feedback    
1     true            false               false                     true
2     false           false               true                      true
3     false           false               false                     false
```

As far as I know, the json ->> functionality was not available in Redshift's outdated Postgres version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that these are strings in Redshift that contain json (not the new Super data type).  Redshift has several json parsing functions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html

I think you want to use the json_extract_path_text() function -   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html

```
select json_extract_path_text(feature_column, '{reporting}') as reporting from ...
```

Comment: somehow, every value inside the columns is empty(?)

Comment: Let me check that I understand your data correctly - Is your current information 1 string of 3 lines or 3 rows of strings?  For these to be valid json strings these need to be 3 rows of strings but I can see that this may not be what you have going on

Comment: it is 3 rows of strings

Comment: OK this is still doable but you will need to modify the string so that it is a single valid json.  By adding {"line": [ to the beginning and ]} to the end AND commas between the elements with a regexp you can make this a single json array.  Then you can parse the json with the Redshift json functions (nested since you have objects inside of an array).